# Ray tracing: Bresenham's vs Siddon's algorithm

Tags: raytracing, raycasting, voxel, rasterizing, bresenham

I'm developping a tool for radiotherapy inverse planning based in a pencil-beam approach. An important step in these methods (particularly in dose calculation) is a ray-tracing from many sources and one of the most used algorithms is Siddon's one (here there is a nice short description http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2014/poster/pdf/P4218_CT_reconstruction_iterative_algebraic.pdf). Now, I will try to simplify my question:

The input data is a CT image (a 3D matrix with values) and some source positions around the image. You can imagine a cube and many points around, all at same distance but different orientation angles, where the radiation rays come from. Each ray will go through the volume and a value is assigned to each voxel according to the distance from the source. The advantage of Siddon's algorithm is that the length is calculated on-time during the iterative process of the ray-tracing. However, I know that Bresenham's algorithm is an efficient way to evaluate the path from one point to another in a matrix. Thus, the length from the source to a specific voxel could be easily calculated as the euclidean distance two points, even during Bresenham's iterative process.

So then, knowing that both are methods quite old already and efficient, there is a definitive advantage of using Siddon instead of Bresenham? Maybe I'm missing an important detail here but it is weird to me that in these dose calculation procedures Bresenham is not really an option and always Siddon appears as the gold standard.

Thanks for any comment or reply!

Good day.

Comment: Just want to comment on Siddon's method, where it only accounts the length that the path travels inside each voxel. However, in the scenario where fan-beam is used, the width of the beam itself changes as it travels, which means the same path, the attenuation will be different depending the position X-ray source sits. Magnification maybe the correct terminology for this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in most applications involving medical ray tracing, you want not only the distance from a source *to* a particular voxel, but also the intersection lengths of that path with every single voxel on its way. Now, Bresenham gives you the voxels on that path, but not the intersection lengths, while Siddon does.